# mongodb updateOne method is not working with mongoose 5.4.10

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update record of mongodb using updateOne method but it's not working.

```
async function updateCourse(id) {
   const result = await  Course.updateOne({_id : id }, { name: 'Abc'}, 
         function(err, res) {});
   console.log(result);
}
```

anyone please suggest possible solution to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
const test = async function updateCourse(id) {
  const result = await Course.updateOne({ _id: id }, { name: "Abc" })
  console.log(result);
};
```

If you using async await, don't use callback again

I hope this can help you. Thank you

Comment: Not getting any error but record not updated. This is my output for this code:         { n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }

Comment: I've faced the same issue when I forgot to include an updated field to the schema.

Comment: It worked but I couldn’t  understand the reason. Could you please explain more especially difference between sending whole document and sending only id?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, have you try this bro?

```
const result = await Course.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: id }, {  name: "Abc" }, { new: true } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I also could not get this to work.  For me, I had to do:

```
let tempSubDoc = await myDocument.mySubDocument.id(my_id);

tempSubDoc.value1 = val1;
tempSubDoc.value2 = val2;

await myDocument.save();
```

Documentation says that Mongoose will send an UpdateOne command to MongoDb internally when an object is updated and saved: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

Comment: If you use middleware on save like hashing the password, this would hash the hashed password again.

Answer (score 0):

I was thought this would be helpful to someone,

You have to add the required fields to update in the mongoose schema, otherwise it is dropping those  fields , that's why the update is not done.

In this case the "name" field must be added to "Course" schema. Also you can use "await", without using callback function.